# Why this header of "世界日报" is written as "世界曰报"？

Tags: characters, handwriting

See the picture. [image]

There is an obvious mistake: the third character is written as "曰" (yue) instead of "日" (ri). Why it is not written correctly as "日" such as the following?

[image]

Comment: If the two words can be distinguished in the same kind of writing there is no problem. But in this title, we can recognize that it is 日 rather than 曰 from the context, although it is very similar, but it is acceptable.

Comment: @valkjsaaa said that it is 隶书 style so it is right, I don't agree, it still looks like 曰 not 日 even written in 隶书.

Answer (score 4):

It's correctly written, but in a different font called 隶书 [Clerical script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script). It's one of the archaic style of writing. In general Chinese characters in 隶书 look wider, which makes 日 looks like 曰 in regular fonts.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not**.

[zdic](http://www.zdic.net/z/1b/zy/65E5.htm) puts this under the 楷体 font.

> [image]

You can compare this with [zdic](http://www.zdic.net/z/1b/zy/66F0.htm) rendition of 曰 using 楷体.

> [image]

Also context is key, many fonts look different.